# IntelliJ all of Controllers could not autowired all of Services after context seperation

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, transactions, web.xml, spring-context

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1.3.

few days ago, I fixed the setting for Transaction.
but after that, every controllers show up this error(red underlines).

[ Could not autowired. No beans of '~~Service' type found. ]

however, it works fine. so I'm confused..

this is what I fixed.

```
/* context-datasource.xml */

<context:component-scan base-package="a.b">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

/* context-transaction.xml */

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
         <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception"/>
        </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="requiredTx" expression="execution(* a.b..service.impl.*Impl.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="requiredTx" />
</aop:config>

/* dispatcher-servlet.xml */

<context:component-scan base-package="a.b" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

and here my project.

```
/* web.xml */

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/framework/springmvc/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:framework/spring/context-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

/* controller */

@Controller
public class TestController {

    private final CodeService codeService;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(CodeService codeService){ // 'codeService' has a red underlines.
        this.codeService = codeService;
    }

    public TestController(){
        this(null);
    }

/* service */

public interface TestService { ...

/* serviceImpl */

@Service("TestService")
public class TEstServiceImpl implements TestService { ...

/* mapper */

@Mapper("TestMapper")
public interface TestMapper { ...
```

what should I do ?
can I just ignore that underlines or .. ?